# Monitor not displaying color red. Is this the monitor or some setup I'm missing?

Tags: hardware, display, color

I've plugged the monitor into both an iMac 2006 and a MacBook 2008. Red shows up as black. I've set up the monitor in System Preferences and on the monitor itself. The color red simply shows as black. Is there something I'm missing or is the monitor likely broken?

I've searched online and can't find similar issue.

**Edit:** Now I'm *really confused: can't be the monitor, because I tried plugging a different monitor (from a friend's computer) and I have the same problem.

Comment: You mentioned that you set up the monitor via System Preferences. Did you attempt the calibration steps under `System Preferences -> Displays -> [Acer Display name here] -> Color` ?

Comment: Try a different cable. From what you've said it's the only thing you haven't swapped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are applications that let you control how much of each color component in the display generated by your machine gets to the monitor. An example of this is [Dark Adapted](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/12134/darkadapted/).

These are useful for adjusting your monitor for night time viewing, and other special cases. Unless you have something like this running on BOTH the machines, it's likely that the problem is either with the monitor itself, or with the cable.

Are you connecting via VGA or DVI? A problem with the cable wouldn't manifest like that on DVI, but could on VGA, where individual pins literally correspond to component colors. If on VGA, try another cable and see if that helps. If that doesn't work, it's most likely that the monitor is broken.

Comment: could it be the mini-DVI adapter? it's the only thing in common. Other than that, different machines, different monitor types, different cables.

Comment: Could be, especially if it's the only thing common to all the setups you've tried.

Comment: Well I guess I won't find out until I return it. It's brand new though... but I hope that's the problem because otherwise I'm screwed. -- Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that your edit says that two different monitors have the same problem, I'm guessing it's either the OS's color calibration or the pins on the cable/port.  I'd try a new cable, first, as it's the easiest thing to do and the most likely culprit. If that doesn't work, check the color calibration under System Preferences > Displays > Color. If *that* doesn't work, check the port on your computer and see if there's anything obviously wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

My Acer monitor lost the red color before.  I found no answer to the problem.  One day I wiggled the cable and the red color came back. The same problem and remedy repeated many time. Today I tried to move the cable to different directions without result.  I guess I have exhausted the possible directions.  But if you have not tried this, it may work for you.

Answer (score -1):

A DVI/VGA monitor from 2009 failed to display ANY RED once connected via VGA today.  It now looks fine after a few hours.
After the fact (I forgot to check) I noticed the Color Profile is different for VGA or DVI input.  DVI input only was used before then.